# How to pass the script path to %run magic command as a variable in databricks notebook?

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, databricks

I want to run a notebook in databricks from another notebook using `%run`. Also I want to be able to send the path of the notebook that I'm running to the main notebook as a parameter.
**The reason for not using `dbutils.notebook.run`** is that I'm storing nested dictionaries in the notebook that's called and I wanna use them in the main notebook.

I'm looking for Something like:

```
path = "/References/parameterDefinition/schemaRepository"
```

```
%run <path variable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's impossible to pass the path in `%run` as variable. You can pass variable as parameter only, and it's possible only in combination with with widgets - you can see the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68483140/18627).  In this case you can have all your definitions in one notebook, and depending on the passed variable you can redefine the dictionary.

There will be a new functionality coming in the next months (approximately, see [public roadmap webinar](https://databricks.com/p/webinar/databricks-product-roadmap-webinar) for more details) that will allow to import notebooks as libraries using the `import` statement. Potentially you can emulate the same functionality by exporting the notebook into the file on disk using the [Export command of Workspace API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#export), decoding the data & importing file's content, for example, if you have notebook called `module1` with content

```py
my_cool_dict = {"key1": "abc", "key2": 123}
```

then you can import it as following:

```py
import requests
import base64
import os


api_url = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().apiUrl().get()
host_token = "your_PAT_token"

path = "/Users/..../module1"

# fetch notebook
response = requests.get(f"{api_url}/api/2.0/workspace/export",
    json = {"format": "SOURCE", "path": path},
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {host_token}"}
  ).json()

# decode base64 encoded content
data = base64.b64decode(response["content"].encode("ascii"))

# write the file & __init__.py, so directory will considered a module
dir = os.path.join("/tmp","my_modules")
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir)

with open(os.path.join(dir, os.path.split(path)[-1]+".py"), "wb") as f:
  f.write(data)
with open(os.path.join(dir, "__init__.py"), "wb") as f:
  f.write("\n".encode("ascii"))

# add our directory into system path
import sys
sys.path.append(dir)

# import notebook
from module1 import my_cool_dict
```

and see that we got our variable:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Magic commands such as `%run` and `%fs` do not allow variables to be passed in.

The workaround is you can use `dbutils` as like `dbutils.notebook.run(notebook, 300 ,{})`

Comment: The reason for not using dbutils.notebook.run is that I'm storing heavily nested dictionaries in the notebook that's called and I wanna use them in the main notebook.

Comment: Best answer so far: succinct and actually provides a solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass arguments as documented on Databricks web site:
https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html#use-widgets-with-run

In the top notebook you can call

```
%run /path/to/notebook $X="10" $Y="1"
```

And then in the sub notebook, you can reference those arguments using the widgets API as in

```
x_value = dbutils.widgets.get("X")
y_value = dbutils.widgets.get("Y")
```

To your specific question, it would look something like this where "path" is the variable to be referenced via the widgets API in the target notebook:

```
 %run /path/to/notebook $path="/path/to/notebook"
```

Comment: you can't run a notebook referenced as variable, you can path only a parameter of the notebook...

Comment: Hey, @ARCrow! You should accept this answer, give the guy some credit.

Comment: As Alex pointed out, the "$path" is only going to be a parameter sent to the notebook that "%run" command is going to run. I want to send the path to the executing notebook ("/path/to/notebook") as a parameter to the "%run" command.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You can't pass it as a variable while running the notebook like this:

**In notebook1:**

```
path_var = "/some/path"
```

```
%run ./notebook2
%path=path_var
```

### Solution

However what you can do, and what I did, is access the dbutils object or the variable of notebook1 in notebook2:

**In notebook1:**

```
dbutils.widgets.text("path","", "")
path_var = "/some/path"
```

```
%run ./notebook2
```

**Then in notebook2:**

```
"""
No need to define path widget in Notebook2 like this:
dbutils.widgets.text("path","", "")
"""
path = dbutils.widgets.get("path")
print(path)
```

Output: `/some/path`

```
"""
Or you can access the path_var of Notebook1 directly
without defining it anywhere in Notebook2 like this 
"""
print(path_var)
```

Output: `/some/path`

So this helps when you are using **complicated variables** such as heavily **nested dictionaries8** in the notebook.

### Benefit

What I love about this approach is that **environment of notebooks get shared** when you call a notebook, meaning you can **access variables & methods of Notebook1 in some Notebookn** and vice versa such that:

- Notebook1 is calling Notebook2
- Notebook2 is calling Notebook3
  .....
- Notebookn-1 is calling Notebookn

Comment: What's the point of accessing the dbutils object or the variable of notebook1 in notebook2? The objects that I wanna access are spread across multiple notebooks, and I wanna only run the notebook that hold the object applicable to the run instance.

Comment: This works for me, I can see %run command shares context between notebooks. Thanks @Shaswat