# Importing ipynb file from another ipynb notebook in azure databricks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to import ipynb notebook from another notebook in Azure Databricks using

```
from ipynb.fs.full.test_1 import *
```

While importing I am getting the following key error

KeyError: '**package**'

Here is my test code

```
class Test1:
  def t1():
      a=10
      b= 10
      c= a+b
      return c
Test1.t1()
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: you mean notebooks inside Azure Databricks?

Comment: @AlexOtt Yes. Inside Azure Databricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notebooks in the Databricks aren't the real files - they are something like an entry in the database not stored on the file system.  Because of this you can't use Python's `import` to code from one notebook into another.

Right now it's possible to use `%run` to include content of one notebook into another (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#run)), for example, to implement testing of notebooks.  Just split your code into two pieces:

1. Notebook with functions that you want to test (name it `functions`, for example):

```py
def func1(....):
 ....
```

2. And in the notebook with test code put the following as a separate cell

```
%run ./functions
```

this will include the whole content of the first notebook into context of the second notebook.

I have a [demo project](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-projects-demo) that shows how to use this approach to test notebooks on Databricks.

P.S. There is a workaround by downloading the notebooks onto local file system, adding them to `sys.path`, etc., but it's cumbersome - you can find an example in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68885950/how-to-pass-the-script-path-to-run-magic-command-as-a-variable-in-databricks-no/68888776#68888776).

Comment: I have tried using %run it is working fine. But I how can I capture the output of the %run command? So that I can be able to use the output values in my current notebook.

Comment: `%run` just evaluates the code from specified notebooks - this means that you have functions & variables defined there, then they are becoming available in the notebook that called the `%run` - just use them

Comment: Ya! Thank you so much. It works as expected.

Comment: please look onto demo that I linked - it will help you to integrate these tests into CI/CD pipelines, etc.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.