# How to run notebook inside another notebook in databricks?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

How to pass the dynamic path to %run command in databricks because the function used in another notebook needs to be executed in the current notebook?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass the script path to %run magic command as a variable in databricks notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68885950/how-to-pass-the-script-path-to-run-magic-command-as-a-variable-in-databricks-no)

Answer (score 0):

dbutils.notebook.run(path = dbutils.widgets.get(), args={}, timeout='120')