# How to %run a list of notebooks in Databricks

Tags: python, ipython, databricks

I'd like to %run a list of notebooks from another Databricks notebook.

```
my_notebooks = ["./setup", "./do_the_main_thing", "./check_results"]
for notebook in my_notebooks:
   %run notebook
```

This doesn't work ofcourse. 
I don't want to use `dbutils.notebook.run()` as this creates new jobs and doesn't return anything back - I want everything executable and queryable from the main notebook.

I thought perhaps it might be possible to import the actual module and run the function.

`?%run` shows the command points to IPython/core/magics/execution.py
and `run` is a method of the class `ExecutionMagics` in the module `execution`.
So perhaps, I could use `execution.ExecutionMagic.run()` if I created an instance of the class.

But it's beyond me - tricky and I'm doubting it's an effective solution.

How can this be done?

Am I really stuck with:-
`%run ./a notebook`

`%run ./another_notebook`

`%run ./yet_another_hardcoded_notebook_name`

Eternally grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do - `%run` doesn't allow to pass notebook name as a variable (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68885950/how-to-pass-the-script-path-to-run-magic-command-as-a-variable-in-databricks-no/68888776#68888776) with more details, and possible workaround).

Another approach would be to use so-called [arbitrary files in repos](https://docs.databricks.com/repos/work-with-notebooks-other-files.html#work-with-python-and-r-modules) functionality - if you define code as a Python file instead of notebook, then you'll be able to use it as normal Python module, and even load it dynamically if you need.